# I2C interface between Artix and MAX30102 Oxymeter

Tags: vhdl, i2c

I don't see any acknowledgement signal from sensor to FPGA Artix7 after sending the start condition. What could be the problem?

[image: Logic Analyzer Screenshot D0 is SCL, D1 is SDA]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please insert the image in our question. Please add your code, test bench, etc. "Please help me" is not a proper question. Please read ["How to ask a question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First, follow @JHBonarius advice. Second, you don't provide any clock : scl should act like a clock after the start condition.

Comment: @keerthi Why do you expect an acknowledge after the start condition? Only transfers are acknowledge. You will have to clock out the slave address (SLA) and R/#W, which would then get acknowledged by a slave with that address.

Comment: What is the time resolution? I see only voltages (y scale), but no time (x scale). You might need to zoom out. I²C is not very fast ...

Comment: @Paebbels It's 5 ns /div (upper middle)

Comment: So we see circa 50 ns. Let's assume a a regular I²C speed of with 100 kBd. So one bit has 10 us. So your some needs to decrease by 200 to see at least one bit, not speaking of a complete I²C word (factor 2000).